# Regular Expression Validator to catch non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: .net, regex

This is a really dense question, but I'm tired.

I need a regular expression that can do in a validator control that will catch any non-alphanumeric characters. In other words the regexp needs to match if the string contains only a-z, A-Z or 0-9.

I'm aware that it's quite easy to write a regular expression that will match if there's an illegal character in a string - the trouble is that I need the *opposite* of this because it's in a validator. Thats' what's giving me a headache.

Solutions appreciated.r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your set of acceptable characters are `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. You want to validate on anything that doesn't match those, so use a `^` to negate this character class:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

In addition, make sure you use a RequiredFieldValidator along with your RegularExpressionValidator since the latter doesn't catch blank entries. [Per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e.aspx):

> If the input control is empty, no
>   validation functions are called and
>   validation succeeds. Use a
>   RequiredFieldValidator control to
>   prevent the user from skipping an
>   input control.

Answer (score 0):

If empty string is not valid:

```
^[[:alnum:]]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```